# How do you disable HornetQ in jboss6

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x, hornetq

```
09:13:41,660 INFO  [HornetQServerImpl] HornetQ Server version 2.1.2.Final (
Colmeia, 120) stopped
```

Would like to understand how to disable HornetQ component while launching JBoss6. We don't use this component and I am under the impression that the core engine might not have a dependency either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cd $JBOSS_HOME/server/YOUR-SERVER/deploy
rm -r hornetq
cd $JBOSS_HOME/server/YOUR-SERVER/deployers
rm hornetq-deployers-jboss-beans.xml
```

where `YourServer = All|Default|AnyOtherProfileYouCreated`

Comment: Optionally you may also try removing the jms-ra.rar directory. But I'm not sure if there are dependencies on the MDB layer.